# Как вставлять данные в таблицу и одновременно их изменять?

Tags: c#, sql

Есть такой запрос:

```
Insert into Таблица2(Код, Столбец2, Столбец3...)
Select Код, Столбец2, Столбец3... From Таблица1 
Where Таблица1.СтолбецN = '...'
```

Необходимо, чтобы при копировании строк из Таблицы1 в Таблицу2, поле Код уже имело новое значение. Допустим (MAX(Таблица1.Код) + 1). Как это сделать одним запросом?

Comment: Это сильно зависит от используемого диалекта sql, который вы в вопросе не указали. Проще всего было бы сделать Код автоинкрементным полем в таблице2 и вообще не указывать его в запросе, что бы БД назначила значение сама. Либо использовать в select какое нибудь вычисляемое выражение вместо Код, а вот оно как раз зависит от используемого диалекта sql, ибо там потребуется нумеровать записи. Хотя если дырки в нумерации допустимы вполне можно брать max(таблица1)+Таблица2.Код

Comment: @Mike Подскажите, в какую часть запроса вставить выражение max(таблица1)+Таблица2.Код? Я использую Transact-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
Insert into Таблица2(Код, Столбец2, Столбец3...)
Select MaxCode+Таблица1.Код, Столбец2, Столбец3...
  From Таблица1, (select max(Код) MaxCode from Таблица2) x
Where Таблица1.СтолбецN = '...'
```

Предварительно проверьте на select без insert устраивает ли получаемая нумерация